# Basic Layout with WindowsForms

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I create a simple form that has a MenuStrip at the top and a TabControl filling all of the remaining space?

If I go with DockStyle.Top/DockStyke.Fill tabControl fills whole form regardless of MenuStrip:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        initializeComponent();
    }

    private void initializeComponent()
    {
        MenuStrip mainMenu = new MenuStrip();
        mainMenu.Dock = DockStyle.Top;

        TabControl tabs = new TabControl();
        tabs.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        TabPage test = new TabPage("test");
        tabs.Controls.Add(test);

        Controls.Add(mainMenu);
        Controls.Add(tabs);
    }
```

Comment: Use VS Designer instead.

Comment: That doesn't really help me. Designer has to do it programmatically as well. Meaning there must be a way. I don't understand why is the TabControl denying the existence of MenuStrip.

Comment: Exactly.... see VS designer generated code and do the same.

Comment: call `mainMenu.SendToBack()`

Comment: The designer just positions them absolutely.

Comment: It can be done with designer too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the z-order of `mainMenu` or `tabs`. For example you can call:

```
mainMenu.SendToBack();

//Or
//tabs.BringToFront();
```

After adding controls to the controls collection.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach through designer, without writing code manually, so your changes will affect design time too

Use *Document outline* tab and arrange control's hierarchy with your requirements

*View -> Other Windows -> Document outline* or `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T`